# Does the Firefox Web Developer Toolbar have an equivalent of Firebug's "Inspect Element" CSS live-debug feature?

Tags: html, css, firefox, firebug, web-developer-toolbar

To edit CSS, I have to inspect elements in Firebug and then make changes in the Firefox Web Developer toolbar so that I can save the changes out to a separate CSS file.

It would be nice if I could forget about Firebug and just use a single tool. Does the Web Developer toolbar have an "Inspect Element" option? I can't seem to find one.

What this feature does is lets you hover your mouse over structural elements and inspect the associated CSS.

Comment: Check this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13855134/1868660

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Information -> Display Element Information (Ctrl-Shift-F).

Comment: thanks, been using firebug and never thought to find an alternative!

Answer (score 3):

With CSS > Edit CSS you can also edit the css and preview changes live.