# Firefox: how to stop and inspect new styles added when hovering on an element?

Tags: css, firefox, hover, firefox-developer-tools

I am using Firefox for development.

I would like to see what CSS styles are added to A tag when I hover the mouse over it. How can I do this in Firefox?

**UPDATE**

I right-clicked on the tag and select inspect the element. I can see the styles added to the bottom right pane. However, if I move the mouse to the css pane to examine styles, then the added CSS styles disappear. I understand that I may need to break on something, but I cannot get it working.

Thanks!

Comment: Docs (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720254/how-can-i-see-hover-and-active-properties-of-elements-on-a-webpage#comment51148487_8723462)): https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/page_inspector/how_to/examine_and_edit_css/index.html#viewing-common-pseudo-classes

Answer (score 7):

1. Right click → <kbd>Inspect Element</kbd>
2. Select the "Inspector" tab
3. Find the element that you want to examine inside your markup
4. Right click (on the selected element) → <kbd>Change Pseudo-class</kbd> → <kbd>:hover</kbd>
5. Check the CSS `Rules` tab to see what changes occur.

This is the way to force `:hover` state when your mouse is not over an element.

Comment: "Hover" is now in a submenu, so step 4 is:  "Right click (on the selected element), Change Pseudo-class > hover."

Comment: Thanks @MarkBerry 

Comment: Now we can also left-click on the element in the inspector, then at the top of the css tab you can click on `:hov` to toggle _hover_, _focus_ and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Right click - choose "inspect element"

Comment: I did that many times. I need to break on something, but I simply cannot get it right. Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 0):

How easy. Right click on your element than choose "inspect element" option.